# Drupal - Redirect success message to shadowbox

Tags: ajax, drupal, shadowbox

I've got a typical webform that submits using the [ajax](http://drupal.org/project/ajax) module. How can I redirect the success message to a [shadowbox](http://drupal.org/project/shadowbox)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This involved a JS hook. The AJAX drupal plugin sends drupal's messages to its javascript component.

Answer (score 0):

Read about lighboxing here: http://thedrupalblog.com/inserting-form-lightbox-window-and-submitting-it-ajax

 I assume it's the same, just for "rel" you should use "shadowbox"